# Why always default on switch clause?

Tags: javascript

```html
<input id="choice" placeholder="Enter your choice">
<button type="submit" onclick="operate()">Submit</button>
<script>
   
function operate(){
    let choice = document.getElementById("choice").value //value entered in textbox assigned to variable choice
      
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            add();
            break;
        case 2:
            sub();
            break;
        case 3:
            mul();
            break;
        case 4:
            div();
            break;
       
        default:
            alert("Invalid Entry");
    }
}
```

Only default case is working.But its working when i used prompt() function to get the value to variable choice

Comment: I've no clue what is asked here. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you ever `console.log(choice);` and see what you were getting?

Comment: tried console.log(choice),its displaying the value i gave.but in switch,default case is only working.

Answer (score 0):

You just parse your variable switch (parseInt(choice))

Comment: it worked.Im new at javascript and new at here.Thank you :)